# Different options for package installations on Linux / Windows

Tags: r, r-package, apache-arrow

I have develope R package findata which contains `arrow` R package:
https://github.com/MislavSag/findata/blob/main/DESCRIPTION

I can install R package on Windows, but on linux it the package never finishes installation because of the timeout error.
I have found the solution. It seems that I need to install the arrow package in Linux with following commands:

```
options(
  HTTPUserAgent =
    sprintf(
      "R/%s R (%s)",
      getRversion(),
      paste(getRversion(), R.version["platform"], R.version["arch"], R.version["os"])
    )
)

install.packages("arrow", repos = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest")
```

I don't know is it possible to use different arguments when installing R packages during package build. When the platform is windows I need to use `install.packages("arrow")`, but when I am on Linux I need to use above installation command.

Is it possible to implement this in R package?

Comment: It isn't quite clear to me what the problem is on linux. You mention a timeout, but that could be for many reasons. Also, which repo(s) are you attempting to use on linux when you aren't resorting to using Posit's packagemanager? Finally, the above _works_, and even better it installs a binary package, which means it is faster; what is wrong with the above?

Comment: Above works, but I need to import arrow inside the package, which means I have to use above code to install arrow on linux and `install.packages('arrow')` on windows, besause install.packages('arrow') doesn't work on linux

Comment: That is not how packages in R work. Your package can suggest that it needs `"arrow"` by use of the `Imports:` or `Suggests:` fields in your `DESCRIPTION` file. It should not attempt to actually install a package; even if CRAN allowed it (they do not, I believe), it is bypassing R's already-established mechanism for dealing with dependent packages. One option for you, though, is to keep `arrow` in `Suggests:` (so that it can still be installed in the absence of it), and then provide a convenience function that does the above to install it (for whatever reason compels you to attempt that).

Comment: This convenience function could use `R.version["os"]` or similar to differentiate whether the simpler `install.packages("arrow")` is sufficient or if you need to use Posit's packagemanager.